# Let $\varphi : \Bbb R [x] \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $f(x) \mapsto f(2+i)$. Find the generator for the kernel $\ker\varphi$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\varphi : \Bbb R [x] \to \Bbb C$ be defined by  $f(x) \mapsto f(2+i)$. Find the generator for the kernel $\ker\varphi$.

I have that $\ker \varphi =\{g \in \Bbb R[x] \mid \varphi(g(x)) =g(2+i)=0 \}$ so the kernel is the set of polynomials for which $2+i$ is a root.

Now I can write any $g \in \ker \varphi$ as $g(x)=(x-2+i)q(x)$ for a polynomial $g \in \Bbb R[x]$ with $\deg(q)=n-1$.

It would look as if I would need to be able to find a minimal polynomial $g$ which has $2+i$ as it's root here?

I don't know how I can start to find a general form for a polynomial given a singular root of it. Is there a general way to do this? The exercise seems pointless if this can be done only for some "known" polynomials for which we know that for example $2+i$ is a root of.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal polynomial is $g(x) = (x-2)^2+1$, since $g(2+i) = ((2+i)-2)^2 + 1 = i^2+1=-1+1=0$.

Comment: How did you find the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Minimal polynomial of $i$ over the reals is $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If a complex number is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then its complex conjugate is too. There are no other restrictions on what the polynomial can be.

So $2+i,2-i$ are roots i.e. $x-2-i,x-2+i$ are factors so the polynomial is a multiple of $(x-2-i)(x-2+i)=x^2-4x+5$.

So $g\in \ker\varphi \iff \exists f:g(x)=(x^2-4x+5)f(x)$ and $f$ is a polynomial.