# Identify the ring $\Bbb Z[i] / \langle2+i\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Identify the ring $\Bbb Z[i] / \langle2+i\rangle$.

So in this ring we have that $2+i=0 \implies i=-2$ so $i^2 = 2 \implies -1=2$.

I also know that $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle \cong \Bbb Z[i]$ by the homomorphism $ \Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z[i]$ sending $x \longmapsto i$.

The way I think of this is that I would need to find some map from $\Bbb Z[i]$ that has it's kernel generated by $\langle 2+i \rangle$ so do I have to find the minimal polynomial for which $2+i$ is a root? Using sage I've managed to find that it's $x^2-4x+5$, but I don't know if this is useful here?

Comment: "$i=-2$ so $i^2 = 2$" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The minimal polynomial of $i+2$ over the integers is $f(x) = (x-2)^2+1$, since $f(i+2) = ((i+2)-2)^2+1 = i^2+1=0$.

Comment: Just for fun: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4410953/121097